# Passing a true value to a boolean

Tags: c#, constructor, boolean

I am trying to learn C# and I am up to an example that uses a boolean. For the life of me I cant figure out why the program isnt noticing that I am trying to pass a value of true to the boolean. Here is the code in the Form.cs:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HappyBirthday birthdayMessage = new HappyBirthday();
        string returnedMessage;

        birthdayMessage.PresentCount = 5;
        birthdayMessage.MyProperty = "Adam";
        birthdayMessage.hasParty = true;
        returnedMessage = birthdayMessage.MyProperty;

        MessageBox.Show(returnedMessage);

    }
}
}
```

Here is the Class that I created:

```
class HappyBirthday
{

//====================
//  CLASS VARIABLES
//====================
private int numberOfPresents;
private string birthdayMessage;
private bool birthdayParty;

//===========================
//  DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
//===========================
public HappyBirthday()
{
    numberOfPresents = 0;
    //birthdayParty = false;
}

//===========================
//      METHOD
//===========================
private string getMessage(string givenName)
{

    string theMessage;

    theMessage = "Happy Birthday " + givenName + "\n";
    theMessage += "Number of presents = ";
    theMessage += numberOfPresents.ToString() + "\n";

    if (birthdayParty == true)
    {
        theMessage += "Hope you enjoy the party!";
    }
    else
    {
        theMessage += "No party = sorry!";
    }

    return theMessage;
}

//================================
//      READ AND WRITE PROPERTY
//================================
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return birthdayMessage; }

    set { birthdayMessage = getMessage(value); }
}

//================================
//     WRITE-ONLY PROPERTY
//================================
public int PresentCount
{
    set { numberOfPresents = value; }
}

public bool hasParty
{
    set { birthdayParty = value; }
}

}
```

Now I set the initial value to false (even though if my understanding is correct that should be the default value), but when I try to set it = true, the program does not recognize it. Am I supposed to pass a boolean differently then I would a string or int?

Comment: Just wondering if you've [set a breakpoint and ran it through a the debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4607yxb0(v=vs.100).aspx)?  You can learn a lot about your logic flow and why things aren't working by doing that.  It's perfectly OK to ask here, mind you,just offering a tip in case you weren't aware of how to do that.

Comment: After 9 hours of working and studying my brain is fried, I totally forgot about stepping through the code. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're setting `MyProperty` before you're setting `hasParty`.  `getMessage()` is not being called every time `MyProperty` is polled.

Comment: Thank you so much, I cant believe it was only that. I thought I was going crazy. I will accept your answer when the site allows me.

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer. Also, this whole MyProperty idea is not a good implementation. A function that uses this class should be able to treat each property as an associated field or object. MyProperty represents a person's name if you are setting, but a birthday message if you are getting. Instead, make a Name property and a message property. The message will have a getter, but no setter, and the getter uses the Name value that you have set. And if no name is set, it could give a different message, like "Who?"

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Mark, Im sure there is a better way to code it but I am trying to follow this tutorial as much as possible. I am starting to realize, as helpful as it is, I will get more out of coming up with my own projects and learning through coding my own things.

Comment: @user2405778: I've also had tutorials that perhaps did more harm than good.  My recommendation is to follow it closely until you get your code compile and run correctly, and then refactor it until you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The way `MyProperty` works is confusing, because the `set` and `get` deal with different values (you `set` the name, and then `get` the whole message, which is confusing). I'd replace it with a `GivenName` property and then make the `GetMessage()` (or expose it as a read-only property `Message`) `public`.

Also, you can make your code much simpler by using [auto-properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) (you can use `private get`s to keep the write-only behavior, though in the real world write-only properties are very rare, and you should probably just make them public like the `set`s). And since the default `int` value is `0`, you don't need to specify your default constructor. Here's how the code looks now:

```
class HappyBirthday
{
    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            string theMessage;

            theMessage = "Happy Birthday " + GivenName + "\n";
            theMessage += "Number of presents = ";
            theMessage += PresentCount.ToString() + "\n";

            if (HasParty)
            {
                theMessage += "Hope you enjoy the party!";
            }
            else
            {
                theMessage += "No party = sorry!";
            }

            return theMessage;
        }
    }

    public string GivenName { private get; set; }

    public int PresentCount { private get; set; }

    public bool HasParty { private get; set; }
}
```